# editar função python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou escrevendo um algoritmo que calcula a media de variáveis continuas e eu passo para ele uma função com a função especifica:

```
def media_variavel_continua(func, ini, fim):
    return quad(func, ini, fim)


resp = media_variavel_continua(lambda x: (x**2)/3, 1, 3)
```

Acontece que a media de uma variável continua é a própria função vezes 'x', então eu queria conseguir reescrever dentro media_variavel_continua() a função passada.

No exemplo a cima a função (x^2)/3 no final teria que ficar x*(x^2)/3.

Existe alguma forma de fazer isso?

Comment: Nesse caso acredito que você possa tentar fazer uma nova ```lambda x: x*func(x)```. Mas acredito que modificar uma lambda genericamente falando seja mais complicado.

Comment: @Naslausky isso deu certo, obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como comentado, você não precisa **editar** a função, basta criar uma nova que faz o proposto:

```py
def media_variavel_continua(func, ini, fim):
    return quad(lambda x: x*func(x), ini, fim)
```